# What are PCI devices?

Tags: hardware, pci

In Linux, the `lspci` command lists all the devices in my laptop (including AGP, USB, SATA, SCSI, bridges, ethernet, etc.). The `man lspci` command gives me this information:

> `lspci` - list all PCI devices

What are PCI devices? Does this relate to PCI bus (or PCI slot)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the manual page of `lspci` says:

> lspci  is  a  utility for displaying information about PCI buses in the    system and devices connected to them.

So it lists all (PCI) devices connected to the PCI bus(es). Looking at a PCI id, e.g. `03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)`, the `03:00.0` is the PCI bus slot (`bus:device.function`), the `Network controller` part is the PCI slot class and the final text part is a description of the device.

**Edit** in response to the comment below:
According to [The Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/PCI), `lspci` lists the PCI-like devices (AGP, PCI-Express, CardBus, Express Card, etc) that are connected to your computer. I guess it lists all devices directly connected to the north bridge, south bridge and, for more recent computers, the PCH.

Note that USB devices can be listed using `lsusb` and CPU information via `lscpu`. The `lshw` tool gives an even more detailed view of the hardware.

Comment: AFAIK, PCI bus connects SouthBridge and peripheral controllers while AGP is connected to NorthBridge, so, why AGP is classified as a PCI device?

Comment: Ah, I see. I updated the answer to better reflect your question.